# Flash Builder 4.5 Drop Downlist with Checkbox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, checkbox, drop-down-menu, flash-builder

So the problem I am currently having is that I have A drop down list that is populated by xml and I want to make it so I can select multiple rows in the list by adding a check box control. I can easily add the check box by using a custom item renderer, and it shows up for each item in the list but I cant select any of the check boxes only individual items in the list. How can i solve this problem?

I appreciate any help in advance

thanks

Comment: You'll have to extend the component so that the drop down doesn't close when an item is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of the click event in the handler for the click on the check box with event.stopImmediatePropagation();

Also to note since we also did this you'll need to keep track of the selected value in the data for the list.

Comment: thanks, so i found someone who has extended the dd class to work exactly like I wanted, but now I am having a problem accessing the array of selected check boxes to use in the rest of my app...his extension has a method called selectedViews, but it is not working for me. here is the link to the source code http://blastanova.com/labs/multiselectdropdown/srcview/index.html...thanks again